# Gradient color display in Nexus 3 Spartan 6 FPGA - VHDL

Tags: vhdl, gradient, fpga, display, vga

I am trying to display a color gradient using the Spartan 6 board. Since Spartan 6 board which I am currently using supports only 8 bits for the VGA, I am not able to display RGB colors without hard borders.  I have already displayed an RGB color with hard borders by coding like this

```
            if x>0 and x<50 then
                rgb <= RED;  
            elsif x>= 50 and x<100 then
                rgb <= GREEN;  
            elsif x>= 100 and x<150 then
                rgb <= BLUE;  
            elsif x>= 150 and x<200 then
                rgb <= WHITE; 
            elsif x>= 250 and x<300 then
                rgb <= RED;  
            elsif x>=350 and x<400 then
                rgb <= GREEN;  
            elsif x>= 400 and x<450 then
                rgb <= BLUE;  
            elsif x>= 450 and x<500 then
                rgb <= WHITE;  
            end if;
```

But now I have to display a color gradient without hard borders. I am currently working with a screen resolution of 640x480. I am thinking of using LUT for giving all possible combinations by giving index. I need some advice on how this can be done in VHDL or Is there any other way to implement this without explicitly coding all combinations with conditions?

How to achieve a moving color gradient pattern with these color gradients?

Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: As you said : you need a Look-Up-Table, in your case 256 entries. Yes: you have to define all 256 entries. Alternative you can make a dual-ported LUT with a CPU interface and fill the table from a processor.

Comment: Is it possible to display a moving color gradient pattern with these colors?

Comment: You haven't given us any of the signal or constant declarations so we can only guess. But in outline, `rgb <= f(x);` will do; all you need to do is write the body of function `f`;

Comment: I have done something like this

'constant  RED : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)  := "11100000";
constant  GREEN : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)  := "00011100"; 
constant  BLUE : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)  := "00000011"; 
constant  WHITE : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)  := "11111111"; 
constant  BLACK : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)  := "00000000";'

then used the above conditions to display RGB colors, I am not sure how to display a moving color gradient.

Comment: I suggest you look up how RGB works By the way many tools (e.g. paint) have a colour GUI which lets you type in the R,G an B value and how you what comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a 8 bits per component (24 bit RGB) or 8 bit per color (8-bit RGB) ? In the second case you'll have a hard time displaying gradients. Not impossible, but much harder.

Let's assume you have a 24 bit case. With a step of 50 it will require some mid-to-heavy logic, or a big selection vector. But it will get much simpler if you set it to, say, 64.

Look:

```
R(7 downto 2) <= X(5 downto 0) when X(11 downto 6) = "000000" else
                 31-X(5 downto 0) when X(11 downto 6) = "000001" else
                 "000000"
```

will give you a black-to-red-to-black gradient 128 pixels wide on the left side of the screen.

You can combine it with 2 other colors to get the desired effect.

Comment: It's 8 bit per color, creating 256 different colors for each unique 8-bit pattern. I am attaching the link for the reference manual for the board I am using for my project for your reference.
https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/programmable-logic/nexys-3/reference-manual
Kindly let me know if you have any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, i see. That's what i was afraid of when talking about hard time with 8-bit case gradients. What you have here is a pure 3-3-2 RGB, This literally means you have only 2 bits of blue, and 3 bits of red/green. This color scheming was never intended to do any gradients by design. But there are some hardware tricks you can employ to actually make gradients. You will need an higher frequency PWMs at LSB bits (say, at x4 VGA, ~100 MHz), and by setting their duty cycle you can set "fractional bits". 4x clock will give you 2 additional bit depth, 8x will give 3 bits, but it's a 200 MHz, so beware.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion!